# Auto Start Teams Meeting using Power Automate Flow

Tags: microsoft-teams, dynamics-365, power-automate

Currently I'm able to create a teams meeting using Power Automate Flow.
However, the meeting still needs to be started by the creator of the meeting.

How to sort of "auto-start" the meeting so all that access the meeting can
use the meeting link without waiting the creator to start the meeting?

Comment: Why not use someone else's credentials when creating the meeting? Then they can start it themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming meeting participants are either guest users or users from other organization, so they are not able to start the meeting directly and meeting creator has to admit them in lobby after starting the meeting.
Meeting creator can set who can bypass the lobby. Go to "Meeting options" inside created meeting, and select appropriate option in "Who can bypass the lobby?"
Pass lobbybypasssettings parameter while creating Graph request for creating meeting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/lobbybypasssettings?view=graph-rest-1.0